# For every infinite class C of sets in V the universe is there an infinite set $x$ such that $x\subset C$?

Tags: set-theory

> For every infinite class C of sets in V the universe is there an infinite set $x$ such that $x\subset C$?

I wasn't sure about how to phrase the question, I could have also asked, is V closed under countable pairing? However as far as I know countable means existing a bijection between $\omega$ the successor set and the sets and thus by replacement the answer would be yes.

The question arised from asking if given a class with a well-founded relation (every non-empty set has a minimal element), there must exist a minimal element in the class. If no then there should be some way of defining a set containing elements in the class but no minimal hence reaching a contradiction (because the answer to the question I believe is yes).

Comment: I'm not certain, but if it's infinite, then there should be an injection from $\omega$ into $C$, and the image is (contained in) a set by replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes. Using foundation, any class $C$ can be written as $\bigcup_\alpha C\cap V_\alpha$, and if all the sets in this union are finite, then so is $C$ (the point being that these sets form an increasing chain).

Note that this argument does not use choice. In particular, we did not conclude that $C$ contains a countably infinite set. If we assume choice, then this follows, since any infinite set contains a countably infinite subset.

Comment: And indeed choice is needed, it is consistent to have Dedekind finite classes without it.

Comment: Can we get infinite classes without infinite subsets in the absence of choice and foundation?

Comment: Sure, do Fraenkel's first model from a class.

Comment: It's one of those things that break down when you try to repeat them with forcing and symmetries; but that only shows how brittle these arguments are, and how much they depend on the failure of foundation.

Comment: Im not sure how to take your answer. What I though is the following. Let $\alpha_n$ be the lowest ordinal such that $|C\cap \alpha_n|>n$ (it must exists, otherwise $S$ is finite). Then $\{\alpha_n : n=1,\ldots\}$ must have a supremum ordinal $\alpha$ and $C\cap \alpha$ must be infinite.

Comment: Im so sorry where I write $C \cap x $ I mean $C \cap V_x$. $x$ being an ordinal.